# Building a referral system using Node/React/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I am making a referral system for my website. I have two schema one is user and other is referral. The userschema is as follows:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  refId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "referral",
  },
  link: {
    type: String, },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
})
```

The referral schema is as follows:

```
const ReferralSchema = new Schema({
  referralId: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  link: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
senderMsg: {
type: String},
senderName: {
type: String},
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
})
```

The referral link is created on signup and after that when a user refer the website to his friend/relative or anyone else, he/she will enter the email id and will send the email to the referrer with the referral link.
Now I want to keep the track of the count of those referrals who registered through that referral link and the referral name should be linked to the under the user.
The issue I am facing is that I want to show the referral link like:
http://example.com/invite/abc@gmail.com

How to make this as referral link. Secondly how to add the count of no of user registered and save the count in mongodb.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`How to make this as referral link` - When a user is referring any other user and will type the user email, you can save that partcular instance in the DB and you can also track if the referred user is signing from the link or not. You can set a flag(boolean), if a user've clicked on their referral link.

`how to add the count of no of user registered and save the count` - As for the count part, when you will track if any of the referred user signed up or not via a link, you can get a count as well(you've to run a query on that flag).

```
link: {
    text: String,
    isClicked: Boolean,
  },
```

Comment: can you please post the sample code for this. I am unable to handle this as I am in learning phase and this is my first project. Thanks in advance. @Yash:

Comment: The more I think about it, you should also change the structure of your link. You should never reveal anybody's email(it's a bad practise). So what you can do is you can set a referral string for every user and then send an invite to every other user based on that. I updated the answer with the new schema.

Comment: Thanks @Yash: for the help. One more thing can I get your email. How to add a list of registered referred users in user schema.

Comment: I think you should not do that because there is no point in doing that. You are already associating the ReferralSchema and userSchema with userId in ReferralSchema. If you really want to do that you can add this code in your userSchema:-
referredUser: {
    type: [String]
  }

Comment: Thanks. I am following this article  https://itnext.io/build-a-referral-system-in-node-express-and-postgres-da56fa4913d4 But in this article its not React and Mongodb can you help in rebuilding with react and mongodb. @Yash:

Comment: Sure. I can help you out. Hit me up on linkedin.

Comment: I have connected you on linkedin. Please check. @Yash: